# Why do I get the error TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'?

Tags: python

```
RNA_codon_dictonary = {
    'UUU': 'F',     'CUU': 'L',     'AUU': 'I',     'GUU': 'V',
    'UUC': 'F',     'CUC': 'L',     'AUC': 'I',     'GUC': 'V',
    'UUA': 'L',     'CUA': 'L',     'AUA': 'I',     'GUA': 'V',
    'UUG': 'L',     'CUG': 'L',     'AUG': 'M',     'GUG': 'V',
    'UCU': 'S',     'CCU': 'P',     'ACU': 'T',     'GCU': 'A',
    'UCC': 'S',     'CCC': 'P',     'ACC': 'T',     'GCC': 'A',
    'UCA': 'S',     'CCA': 'P',     'ACA': 'T',     'GCA': 'A',
    'UCG': 'S',     'CCG': 'P',     'ACG': 'T',     'GCG': 'A',
    'UAU': 'Y',     'CAU': 'H',     'AAU': 'N',     'GAU': 'D',
    'UAC': 'Y',     'CAC': 'H',     'AAC': 'N',     'GAC': 'D',
    'UAA': 'Stop',  'CAA': 'Q',     'AAA': 'K',     'GAA': 'E',
    'UAG': 'Stop',  'CAG': 'Q',     'AAG': 'K',     'GAG': 'E',
    'UGU': 'C',     'CGU': 'R',     'AGU': 'S',     'GGU': 'G',
    'UGC': 'C',     'CGC': 'R',     'AGC': 'S',     'GGC': 'G',
    'UGA': 'Stop',  'CGA': 'R',     'AGA': 'R',     'GGA': 'G',
    'UGG': 'W',     'CGG': 'R',     'AGG': 'R',     'GGG': 'G'
}


def RNA_to_Protien(mRNA_seq):
    codon = []
    if codon in RNA_codon_dictonary:
        # return the aminoacid by looking up in the dictionary:
        return RNA_codon_dictonary[codon]
    else:
        # return '' if we could not translate the codon:
        return '?'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    mRNA_seq = "UCAAUGUAACGCGCUACCCGGAGCUCUGGGCCCAAAUUUCAUCCACU"

    print (RNA_to_Protien(mRNA_seq))
```

Comment: You define `codon` as `[]`.  You then check if `codon` is in `RNA_codon_dictionary`.  `mRNA_seq` is not even involved.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Could I add the following to split mRNA_seq into substrings? and check them?

>n = 2
>codon = mRNA_seq[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(mRNA_seq), n)

Comment: That looks pretty good except that it looks like your strings have length 3.  In that case, you would want `n` to be 3.  Also, you would have to put brackets (`[]`) around the right side of the `codon = ...` assignment.

Comment: >n = 3
>codon = [mRNA_seq[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(mRNA_seq), n)]

Like so?

Comment: Yeah, that looks good.  Now, all you need to do is convert each one to protein.  I would suggest `>protein = "" >for rna in codon: >if rna in RNA_codon_dictionary: >protein += RNA_codon_dictionary[rna] >else: raise ValueError("rna not found")` then after that `for` loop, `return protein`  I'm not sure if I am using the right names, but I think that's the general idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking to see if the empty list is a key in your dictionary. There are two problems with that:

1) The answer will always be no, since your dictionary doesn't have any empty keys, and

2) That operation isn't even allowed, since `list`s are never allowed to be keys of a `dict`.

Based on your comment, the following code might be what you are looking for. It breaks the sequence in non-overlapping substrings of length 3, looks up each substring in the `dict`, and returns all of the results.

```
def RNA_to_Protien(mRNA_seq):
    return [
        RNA_codon_dictonary.get(mRNA_seq[i:i+3], '?')
        for i in range(0, len(mRNA_seq), 3)
    ]
```

In your example sequence, this returns:

```
['S', 'M', 'Stop', 'R', 'A', 'T', 'R', 'S', 'S', 'G', 'P', 'K', 'F', 'H', 'P', '?']
```

Or, if you would rather lookup overlapping sequences, try this:

```
def RNA_to_Protien(mRNA_seq):
    return [
        RNA_codon_dictonary.get(mRNA_seq[i:i+3], '?')
        for i in range(0, len(mRNA_seq)-2, 1)
    ]
```

It yields this result:

```
['S', 'Q', 'N', 'M', 'C', 'V', 'Stop', 'N', 'T', 'R', 'A', 'R', 'A', 'L', 'Y', 'T', 'P', 'P', 'R', 'G', 'E', 'S', 'A', 'L', 'S', 'L', 'W', 'G', 'G', 'A', 'P', 'P', 'Q', 'K', 'N', 'I', 'F', 'F', 'S', 'H', 'I', 'S', 'P', 'H', 'T']
```

And, based on your request to return a single string instead of a list of strings:

```
def RNA_to_Protien(mRNA_seq):
    return ''.join(
        RNA_codon_dictonary.get(mRNA_seq[i:i+3], '?')
        for i in range(0, len(mRNA_seq), 3)
    )
```

This yields:

```
'SMStopRATRSSGPKFHP?'
```

Comment: Ah, I see. how would I break up "UCAAUGUA..." into block of three then and input them into codon? With a range function?

Comment: Do you break them into overlapping or non-overlapping ranges? So A) `'UCA', 'AUG', ...` or B) `'UCA', 'CAA', 'AAU', ...` ? And then, do you look up each 3-character substring? Or just the first?

Comment: I would break them up into non-overlapping ranges (but I'll like to learn how to do it both ways). And I would look up each 3-character sub-string to the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! One more question, how would I modify the code so as it looks up the substring it returns the results to a list? Would that be by a += to a variable or something?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking: "*it returns the results to a list*"? Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: A string. Instead of the output being ['S', ... 'P', 'H', 'T'] I want it to return "SMStopRA..."

Comment: Yes, just use `''.join(...)` instead of `[...]`. See my recent edit.